# Best way to read a numeric string digit by digit in java

Tags: java

So I have actually achieved this but I think that there must be a more correct and efficient solution.

I have to convert a number to binary. I do it by `Integer.toBinaryString(someNumber)` now I have to perform **XOR** on each of the digits in that binary representation. So if my number is `2` which binary representation is `010`, now suppose my another number is `1` or `0`, so I have to perform `0^1,1^1,0^1` or `0^0,1^0,0^0` and create new binary representation.

This is what I have tried and achieved. But I think this is not the best solution. I want a best and efficient solution coz this is required in an image processing algorithm and this process takes place for each pixel. So performance matters..

```
    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(125);
    StringBuilder concat = new StringBuilder();
    char[] numericArr = binary.toCharArray();
            for (char c : numericArr) {
                concat.append((Character.getNumericValue(c)^input2));
            }
    int output = Integer.parseInt(concat, 2);
```

Comment: I'm not saying this is faster, but what about using an int[]? Converting to an int[] might be faster

Comment: Writing a number as a string is the most ridiculously expensive operation you can do to an integer. Why aren't you just using bitwise integer XOR? I've never seen (and cannot imagine) any image-manipulation algorithm that would require strings at all.

Comment: Ok .. i am forced to use String because I have to keep 8 bit representation for byte, which I lose when I use integer for `2` I require `00000010`. Since I already have a API to convert number to binary .. I thought not to write my own. And I am using bitwise integer XOR..

Comment: Why not using bitwise XOR for your integer number like `System.out.println(125 ^ 0xFFFF); // 65410` OR `System.out.println(125 ^ 0x0); // 125`

Comment: I have mentioned in question that I dont have to perform single XOR.. its not `2^1`.. its binary `2` and each of its binary digit with `1`

Comment: That's what bitwise operator does, performs XOR on each bit (125 = binary of `1111101`. So, `1^1, 1^1, 1^1, 1^1, 1^1, 0^1, 1^1` equals to `125 ^ 0xFFFF`

Comment: @mshaaban got your point.... let me try your way..

Answer (score 2):

You really do not want to be going anywhere near strings and the operations you are performing are extremely unnecessarily expensive.

For your use case, I would recommend storing your image in a byte array and iterating through it doing the xor. Something like:

```
byte[] image;
for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
  image[i] ^= 255;
}
```